# Unable to tunnel through proxy

Tags: android-studio, gradle, proxy

I was installing android studio on kali linux 32 bit using the terminal. 
After I run the studio it showed this message:

> Gradle 'MyApplication2' project refresh failed Error:Unable to tunnel
>   through proxy.  Proxy returns "HTTP/1.0 407 Proxy Authentication
>   Required"

What should I do to get rid of this error?